# Totally custom logins in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, web-applications

Can I use the **login:required** feature of **app.yaml** when I create a totally Google separate user login? How? (Google App Engine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The app configuration has no way to know what you consider to be a 'login', so if you're not using the Users API for logins, you need to check if a user is authenticated from within your app. A decorator is commonly used to do this.

Comment: Ok, so as expected I can't use the login : required feature.

I will start with my decorator, thanks Nick!

Comment: @Nick Johnson Can you please suggest a tutorial or something like that?